# Cross tabulation of pair-wise differences

Tags: r

Supposing I have a dataframe with 2 variables corresponding to 2 indices calculated for different groups A, B and C for example. So the dataframe is essentially:

```
 >df
   Group      v.1      v.2
     A         2        3
     B         4        4
     C         7        9
```

I would like to calculate the pair-wise difference per each variable (`v.1` & `v.2`) then plot the result in a cross-tabulation format, so the values below the diagonal gives the pair-wise differences in `v.1` and the upper diagonal, the values for the pairwise differences in `v.2`. So the result would look like:

```
        A       B       C 
   A    0       1       6
   B    2       0       5
   C    5       3       0
```

Is there any package that would help me achieve this? Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably use `combn`+`diff` along with `upper.tri` and `lower.tri` as follows:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nrow(df), 
            dimnames=list(df$Group, df$Group))
m
#   A B C
# A 0 0 0
# B 0 0 0
# C 0 0 0

m[lower.tri(m)] <- combn(df$v.1, 2, FUN=diff)
m[upper.tri(m)] <- combn(df$v.2, 2, FUN=diff)
m
#   A B C
# A 0 1 6
# B 2 0 5
# C 5 3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that smooth as the solution of @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, but one could also approach this with `outer` function from R `base` package:

```
df <- read.table(text =
                   "Group      v.1      v.2
                      A         2        3
                      B         4        4
                      C         7        9",
                 header = TRUE)

# matrix of pairwise differences for v.1
mat_dif1 <- outer(X = df$v.1, Y = df$v.1, FUN = "-")
mat_dif1[mat_dif1<0] <- 0

# matrix of pairwise differences for v.2
mat_dif2 <- outer(X = df$v.2, Y = df$v.2, FUN = "-")
mat_dif2[mat_dif2>0] <- 0

mat_dif1 + abs(mat_dif2)

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0    1    6
## [2,]    2    0    5
## [3,]    5    3    0
```

If you need the row and column names, then:

```
results <- mat_dif1 + abs(mat_dif2)
dimnames(results) <- list(df$Group, df$Group)
results
##   A B C
## A 0 1 6
## B 2 0 5
## C 5 3 0
```